# Android multi module implement private libs with maven authentication

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm modularizing a project and encountering a gradle issue that I can't seem to fix. In this project, I'm implementing private libraries from gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://gitlab.com/api/xxx/-/packages/maven"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Private-Token"
                value = gitlabToken
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I replace this code from build.gradle project by this code on setting.gradle.kts :

```
val properties = java.util.Properties()
val inputStream = java.io.FileInputStream("gradle.properties")
properties.load(inputStream)
val gitlabToken = properties.getProperty("gitlab_token")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = java.net.URI("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/xxxx/-/packages/maven")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
                name = "Private-Token"
                value = gitlabToken
            }
            authentication {
                create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my project, I have this error :

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:commons:generateDevDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:commons:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform mylib-1.0.0.aar (com.libs:mylib:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find mylib-1.0.0.aar (com.libs:mylib:1.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://gitlab.com/api/xxx//-/packages/maven/com/libs/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.aar

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':core:commons:generateDevDebugRFile'.
...
```

Can you tell me what I need to modify in my gradle files to be able to implement these libraries in my modules?

Comment: Hey from the error message, it looks like everything is fine with the credentials, but there is no such file in the maven repository, could you double-check if files exist in given maven repository?

Comment: When I click on the link  https://gitlab.com/api/xxx//-/packages/maven/com/libs/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.aar , the library downloads.